# Using Arcpy UpdateCursor to make calculations based on multiple fields?

Tags: arcpy, cursor

I'm new to Python.

I would like to calculate field values  for a specific 'IDF' based on values from another column.  I have something like that:

```
with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(fc, ['IDF', 'og70_79_sales_sum','SUM_og70_79_103_sales']) as cursor:
for row in cursor:
    if row[0] == 103:
        row[1] = row[2]
        cursor.updateRow(row)
        print('{} - IDF, {} - value, update og70_79_sales_sum: {}'.format(row[0], row[2], row[1]))
```

but it does not work.

Comment: Are you sure the `IDF` field is numeric? It might be a string causing your condition to be `False` everytime

Comment: Yes, IDF is numeric field (double).

Comment: When in "row[1] = row[2]" instead of row [2], I enter a value, for example 100 it is ok. Fields 'og70_79_sales_sum' and 'SUM_og70_79_103_sales' are of the same type.

Comment: You need to fix your formatting--the `for` loop block needs to be indented. The `cursor.updateRow(row)` statement needs to be unindented so that it is directly within the `for` loop. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error. Fields are still empty.

Comment: What information do you need? :) I use ArcGIS 10.2.2. and Python 2.7.5. I read documentation and It seems to me that everything is ok. I must solve this problem because I need to calculate 3000 fields with 16000 rows ;) Maybe I will try with Model Builder.

Answer (score 4):

You stated in a comment that `IDF` is a Double field. However, you are comparing it to an integer, so your `if` statement is probably failing. Try converting the float to an int for the comparison:

```
if int(round(row[0])) == 103:
```

As an aside, I would *highly* recommend storing ID fields as Long/Short/Text, never Float/Double, because comparisons against Float/Double can be extremely unreliable as you see here.

Comment: +1 for never using a float or double field to store an ID value.